# Trying to make a simple MUD like game but having issues with nested loops

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

So I'm a total noob so far and taking a course in JavaScript. I'm supposed to create a simple game with various choices using if, switch and while.

So I got my game going, but it won't recognize user input at some times, and I think it has to do with the way I've nested loops. The following code is inside first a switch and then a while loop. :

```
answer = prompt ("Välj SLÅSS eller PRATA?").toLowerCase();
                                    
if (answer ==="slåss")
{
  console.log("Du närmar dig modigt besten");
  alt = prompt("Använder du magi eller ditt vapen?").toLowerCase;   

 if (alt ==="magi") // this wont work, if I type in magi the code below won't trigger
 {
  console.log("Du kastar en eldboll som visar sig vara supereffektiv. Trollet dör.");
  console.log ("Skattkistan var bakom trollet! Grattis! Du klarade spelet.");
  skog=false;
  break;
                                                
}

                                        
 if(alt==="vapen") // this wont work, if I type in "vapen" the code below won't trigger
 {
  console.log("Du har inte en chans mot trollets styrka i närkamp och dör. Spelet är över.");
  skog=false;
  break;
                                            
}
                
 else
 {
  console.log("Ange ett giltigt alternativ");
                                            
                                            
 }
}
```

I also have an issue where I want a if statement to check if a earlier declared variable is true while also seeing if the user entered string is correct. I've writte this as follows :

```
else if (stark===true && answer === "prata")
```

//here I want you to loose if you choose this option and picked "prata" and "stark" earlier at the start.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing () after `toLowerCase`:

```
  alt = prompt("Använder du magi eller ditt vapen?").toLowerCase;
```

Your code was setting the variable to (lots of terminology here, sorry) a reference to the function `toLowerCase` instead of calling the function and getting its result.

Your second part of the question, about logical flow, seems like it can be solved by restructuring the code. There's an idea of "variable scoping" that will be helpful to you here. Since this is homework, I won't rewrite it for you, but see about declaring those variables as global with `var` at the beginning (as a first step for a beginner--I recognize that global variables are not great programming practice).